# MVC 4 Ajax Asynchronous File Upload Always Passing Null Value To Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I'm having a problem when trying to upload file asynchronously from ajax to my controller. I have 3 variables to pass **(PictureId, PictureName, and PictureFile)**. The problem lies on my "PictureFile" variable which should be holding the uploaded file itself but instead **it always pass null** value to the controller.

**Here is my view model**

```
public class PictureUpload
{
    public int PictureId { get; set; }
    public string PictureName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase PictureFile { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my controller**

```
public JsonResult EditPicture(PictureUpload picture)
{
    //do something here
}
```

**Here is my form**

```
<div class="thumbnail" id="uploadForm">
    <form name="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="fileId" hidden="hidden" />
        <input type="file" name="file" style="max-width: 100%" />
        <input type="button" name="cancel" value="cancel" />
        <span>
            <input type="button" name="upload" value="upload" />
        </span>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Here is my script**

```
$("input[name=upload]").click(function () {
    var $pictureId = $("input[name=fileId]").val();
    var $pictureFile = $("input[name=file]").get(0).files[0];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("EditPicture", "Restaurant")',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ PictureId: $pictureId, PictureName: $pictureFile.name, PictureFile: $pictureFile }),
    });
```

In my controller parameter. **"PictureId"** and **"PictureName"** holds the correct value, but **"PictureFile"** is always null. So it means something is going just not right when the system passes the parameter from ajax to controller. Somehow the system treats **"file"** type differently from others. Could you help me so the file get passed successfully to the controller and tell me what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Check various answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: You need to use `FormData` to upload file using ajax. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: As mentioned by Stephen, you will need FormData, but it will not work in IE8/9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned rightly in the comments use FormData. Below is a code snippet :

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', fileObject);
fd.append('PictureId', pictureId);
fd.append('PictureName', pictureName);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Restaurant/EditPicture',
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {                  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot upload files with AJAX. One way to achieve this is to use a hidden iframe which will simulate an AJAX call and perform the actual file upload or use Flash.

Comment: Suggest you read the links in the comments and Aashish's answer